# I'm having trouble coding a calculator

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator, square-root

I'm getting the syntax error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'unicode' and 'int'

Edit: Okay so this is my new code it'll reset once it's done so you can enter another number until you enter something that isn't a number

```
 while True:
    print 'Welcome to the "Square Root Calculator"'
    print
    number = float(raw_input ('Insert a number: '))
    answer = number ** (1./2)
    print
    if number:
        print ('Square Root: ' + str(answer))
    else:
        break
    print '#=====================================================#'
    print '|                                                     |'
    print '#=====================================================#'
pass
```

Comment: Im not sure but what does  two multiplication mean? **

Comment: THat's exponentiation in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the code in several places- 
First you need to add `int` around `raw_input ('Insert a number: ')`, otherwise `number` is of type str. You also need to add `str` around `answer`, because you cannot add a string and a number. Finally, replace 1/2 with 1./2, as on python 2, 1/2 is 0.
In order to make empty rows, you could add `\n` in the appropriate places.

Here is the corrected version:

```
print 'Welcome to the "Square Root Calculator\n'
number = float(raw_input ('Insert a number:'))
answer = number ** (1./2)
if number:
    print ('\nSquare Root: ' + str(answer))
```

Comment: So adding 'int' before a raw_input makes it so that the character they type in will be characterized as a number?

Comment: Yes, specifically it would be characterized as int. You could replace int with float if you want to allow float inputs as well.

Comment: are there any differences between int and float that could potentially cause code to not work?

Comment: If you want to find the square root of say 5.4, the code will not allow you to do that and will throw an error. So if you need to find a root of non integer numbers as well, you should change the int into float.

Comment: So is it better to just use float all the time so you can use any number?

Comment: Yes definitely use float if you want to allow any input. I updated the answer.

Comment: Okay I wrote a bit of new code with what you gave me and now it loops and if you enter something that isn't a number it closes.

Comment: @Zerp if this has helped solve your problem, consider up-voting or accepting the answer(s) here :)

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` is returning a string, probably - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python), for instance.  Try doing `int(number)` - but be prepared that your person might not give you an integer!